# Are plist files stored with the application bundle?

Tags: ios, plist, icloud, ios8.1

I have an iPad app (XCode 6.1, iOS 8.1 and Storyboards).  I am currently modifying the app to be able to sync it to other devices using iCloud.

My question is:  are all .plist files part of the application bundle? (i.e. do I have to be concerned that if the app is sync'd between devices, do the .plist file(s) go with the app bundle or do I have to move them into the iCloud with the Core Data store)?

Comment: if you save the _.plist_ files to the `Documents` folder from the app explicitly then those files won't be part of the bundle.

Comment: No, they are created once and this code is used to retrieve them:

`NSString *pListPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ColorSchemes" ofType:@"plist"];`

`NSMutableDictionary *plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pListPath];`

Comment: in that case they are permanent part of the bundle.

Comment: If you will re-write your last comment, I will mark it as the answer so you can get the points.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why do you need to sync read-only plist files that are packaged as part of the app?

Comment: Hi Rick... I don't... I just want to make sure that when the iCloud sync'ing is active, and a new user wants to sync to another device (same app), that everything (particularly .plist files) is carried down to the new device.

Comment: I will phrase an anwser then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you save the *.plist* files into the `Documents` folder from the app explicitly then those files won't be part of the bundle.

every other file which is archived into the *.ipa* file when you distribute it, they are permanent part of the bundle.

---

*NOTE: you can read more about the bundle on the official site, e.g. [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html).*